Next-auth useSession return undefined after signIn immediately
I configured next-auth and it is working fine, however I have a login dialog that sent the signIn request and after this request i need to send another request with the user id that is saved in the session, so when I request the session by useSession, it is undefined, but if i requested in any other page, it works fine, my thoughts that it is not ready to be fetched but i need a way to access the user id, or access the response of the login request to the backend not the next-auth signIn response.
Here's the next-auth configurations
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 1800, //time in seconds
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { username, password, locale } = credentials as {
          username: string;
          password: string;
          locale: string;
        };
        let apiRes = null;

        try {
          apiRes = await fetch(
            `${process.env.AUTH_SERVER_URL}/auth/login`,
            {
              method: "POST",
              body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept-Language": locale,
              },
            },
          );
        } catch (err) {
          throw err
        }

        const response = await apiRes?.json();
        if (!apiRes?.ok) {
          throw new Error(
            response?.message ? response.message : "unknown error",
          );
        }
        // If no error and we have user data, return it
        if (apiRes.ok && response) {
          return response.data;
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  // pages for events routing, we are using modal for login
  pages: {
    error: "/",
  },
  debug: true,
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, trigger, session }) {
      if (trigger === "update" && session) {
        session.user = token;
        return session;
      }
      if (user?.user) {
        token.languageCode = user.user.languageCode;
      }

      if (user?.accessToken) {
        token.accessToken = user.accessToken;
      }
      if (user?.refreshToken) {
        token.refreshToken = user.refreshToken;
      }
      if (user?.user?.username) {
        token.username = user.user.username;
      }

      if (user?.user?.id) {
        token.id = user.user.id;
      }
      if (user?.user?.subscriberType) {
        token.subscriberType = user.user.subscriberType;
      }
      return cleanUndefinedProperties(token);
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      // update session info, add the information needed from the interface type
      session.user.accessToken = "";
      if (token?.accessToken) {
        session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      }
      session.user.username = token.username;
      session.user.id = token.id;
      session.user.subscriberType = token.subscriberType;
      session.user.languageCode = token.languageCode;
      // redirect(`/${ session.user.lang }`)
      return cleanUndefinedProperties(session);
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);

function cleanUndefinedProperties(obj: any) {
  const cleanedObj = { ...obj };

  for (const key in cleanedObj) {
    if (typeof cleanedObj[key] === "undefined") {
      cleanedObj[key] = null;
    }
  }
  return cleanedObj;
}

and here is the login dialog
const LoginDialog: FC<Props> = ({ children, setLoggedInSuccess }) => {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    return(
     <Dialog
          open={open}
          onOpenChange={() => {
            setOpen(!open);
            setShowForgetPass(false);
          }}
        >
          {children}
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogClose>
              <Close_x />
            </DialogClose>
    
                <LoginForm
                  setLoggedInSuccess={setLoggedInSuccess}
                  setShowForgetPass={() => setShowForgetPass(true)}
                  setOpen={setOpen}
                />
          
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      );
};

const LoginForm = ({
  setShowForgetPass,
  setOpen,
  setLoggedInSuccess,
}: {
  setShowForgetPass: () => void;
  setOpen: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  setLoggedInSuccess: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}) => {
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      username: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const [loginErrors, setLoginError] = useState<string | undefined>("");
  const [loginLoading, setLoginLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
    setLoginLoading(true);
    const fingerprint = await getFingerprint();
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("accept-language", locale || "ar");

    const res = await signIn("credentials", {
      username: values.username,
      password: values.password,
      redirect: false,
      headers,
    });
    setOpen(true);
    if (!res?.ok) {
      setLoginError(res?.error);
      setLoginLoading(false);
    } else {
      try {
        const fingerprintRes = await postFingerPrint(
          session?.user?.id || "",
          fingerprint as string,
        );
      
        setOpen(false);
        setLoginLoading(false);
        setLoggedInSuccess(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        setOpen(true);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <p>
          {t("login-login")}
        </p>
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="username"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormControl>
                <Input
                  id="username"
                  aria-describedby="username"
                  placeholder={t("login-username")}
                  {...field}
                 
                />
              </FormControl>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="password"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormControl>
                <Input
                  id="password"
                  aria-describedby="password"
                  type="password"
                  placeholder={t("login-password")}
                  {...field}
                 
                />
              </FormControl>

              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
     
        <Button
          disabled={loginLoading}>
          {loginLoading ? (
            <Loading formLoader={true} hideText={true} />
          ) : (
            t("login-login")
          )}
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
};

    export default LoginForm;

I tried to search for a way to customize the response of signIn function to retur the userId insted of calling useSession but didn't find a way.
I also tried to but a useEffect depending on the session and get the userid, but the dialog closd after signIn request succeeds.
I am expecting a way to get the user id either by calling the useSession or not instead of getting undefined session
NB: ${process.env.AUTH_SERVER_URL}/auth/login returns userId and i save it to the session but i can't get the response of this request from client side signIn request.
